# Getting a reader for a byte array

Tags: buffer, rust, reader

I'm trying to test some code which takes a reader. I've got a function:

```
fn next_byte<R: Read>(reader: &mut R) -> ...
```

How can I test it on some array of bytes? The docs say that there's a `impl<'a> Read for &'a [u8]`, which would imply this should work:

```
next_byte(&mut ([0x00u8, 0x00][..]))
```

But compiler disagrees:

```
the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for the type `[u8]`
```

Why? I explicitly said `&mut`.

Using rust 1.2.0

Answer (score 12):

You are trying to invoke `next_byte::<[u8]>`, but `[u8]` does not implement `Read`.  `[u8]` and `&'a [u8]` are not the same type! `[u8]` is an unsized array type and `&'a [u8]` is a slice.

When you use the `Read` implementation on a slice, it needs to mutate the slice in order for the next read to resume from the end of the previous read. Therefore, you need to pass a mutable borrow to a slice.

Here's a simple working example:

```
use std::io::Read;

fn next_byte<R: Read>(reader: &mut R) {
    let mut b = [0];
    reader.read(&mut b);
    println!("{} ", b[0]);
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = &[1u8, 2, 3] as &[u8];
    next_byte(&mut v);
    next_byte(&mut v);
    next_byte(&mut v);
}
```